# What Cross platform technology works for exisiting ASP.NET 2.0 Typed DataSets, SQL Server

Tags: android, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, cross-platform

We have an existing web application with backend SQL Server using ASP.NET VB.NET Typed Data Set, Object Data source technologies. What cross platform technologies we need to use to make this application work on Android Smartphone and Windows/Web browser.
User of smartphone require to enter data on locally and once signal found, the data needs to be sync to the centralized SQL Server.

Comment: .NET does not run on Android. Develop a android application and use web services to communicate with the database.

Comment: Do I need a certain platform to develop an android application that we work together with SQL Server? What web services (technologies) i need to use.

Comment: Android is developed in a Java like environment and is hugely different to .Net. Web services are web services as long as they conform to the WSI profile you can consume them from most devices/applications.

Comment: I know the difference between Android/DOT NET. Just want to know what technology/framework I need to develop Android application to communicate with SQL SERVER.

Comment: Then use web services. As pointed out in the previous comment. .Net can create web services.....